# SceneKit custom geometry: I know multi position(SCNVector). how do I create the custom geometry

Tags: ios, geometry, scenekit

```
SceneKit custom geometry:
```

I know multi position(`SCNVector`).

how do I create the `custom geometry`.

```
the bottom side position:(0,0,0) (50,0,0) (50,0,-50) (150,0,-50) (150,0,125) (0,0,125) (25,0,75) (25,0,50) (0,0,50)
```

[image]

```
the top side position:(0,2,0) (50,2,0) (50,2,-50) (150,2,-50) (150,2,125) (0,2,125) (25,2,75) (25,2,50) (0,2,50),   y—axis move 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a flat shape with a constant height, it would be easiest to create a 2D `UIBezierPath` for that shape and create an extruded `SCNShape` with that path where the extrusion depth is the thickness of your geometry.

Comment: That's great. I solved the problem according to your advice. read your blog before,now you have answered my question,what a coincidence.I will post the sample code to help others . Thank you very much.